# BufferedReader#readLine() hangs even though a line has been read

Tags: java, io

Updated Question (to be more clear):

Is there a way to design the InputStream below such that `BufferedReader#readLine()` will return after reading the new line character?

In the example below, `readLine()` hangs forever even though the reader has read a new line because (presumably) it is waiting for the buffer to fill up.  Ideally, `readLine()` would return after reading the new line character.

I know something like what I want is possible, because when you read from `System.in` using `BufferedReader#readLine()`, it does not wait for the buffer to fill up before returning.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class Example {

    private static final class MyInputStream extends InputStream {

        public final BlockingQueue<String> lines = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        private InputStream current = null;

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            try {
                if(current == null || current.available() == 0)
                    current = new ByteArrayInputStream(lines.take().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                return current.read();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                return -1;
            }
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyInputStream myin = new MyInputStream();
        myin.lines.offer("a line\n");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myin));
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
    }
}
```

Also, if there is a better way to send a string to an InputStream, I'm open to suggestions.

**Accepted Solution:**

Based on a suggestion from Sotirios Delimanolis in one of the comments on his solution, I'm just going to used a `PipedInputStream` instead.  I've coupled it to a `PipedOutputStream`, and `BufferedReader#readLine()` returns immediately as long as I call `PipedOutputStream#flush()` after sending a string that contains a new line character.

Comment: I've checked to make sure that the characters are getting read, and indeed #read() does get called 7 times, first for "a" then " " then "l" ... all the way to the new line character.  So I know that the InputStreamReader is getting everything, but for some reason the BufferedReader does not realize that a full line has been read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After updated question, the only way to get the `BufferedReader` to stop reading after the new line character is to set the buffer size to `1`, which completely removes the need for a `BufferedReader`.

You'll have to write your own implementation.

---

A `BufferedReader` reads more bytes than required. In your case, that means it will read further than the new line character. For example, with the Oracle JVM, it will attempt to read 8192 bytes. Through your inheritance hierarchy, this

```
System.out.println(in.readLine());
```

will attempt to invoke your `read()` method 8192 times.

The first 6 calls will return a value, one for each of the characters in your `String`'s byte array. The next one, will see

```
if(current == null || current.available() == 0)
     current = new ByteArrayInputStream(lines.take().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

and `current.available()` will return 0 since the `ByteArrayInputStream` has been fully consumed. It will then attempt to `take` from the `BlockingQueue` and block indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, if there is a better way to send a string to an InputStream, I'm open to suggestions.

Well, instead of an `InputStream` you can try a `BufferedReader`, with something that looks like this:

```
public int read(String directory) throws Exception{
    String line = "";
    File file = new File(directory);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    do{
        lines.add(br.readLine());
    while(br.readLine() != null);

    br.close();

    return Integer.parseInt(line);
}
```

Comment: Be careful about doing this `lines.add(br.readLine());` in `do/while`  as first `readLine()` can return null

Comment: The task I am faced with is sending strings to an InputStream, so using an InputStream is non-negotiable.  However, I would be willing to consider other, better ways to send string to an InputStream.

Comment: Maybe use an ObjectInputStream?